# How much gold do champion kills give on Proving Grounds?

Tags: league-of-legends

There is a reduction in gold per champion kill on Proving Grounds. I play a lot of it, but never really had the time to watch for the gold gain because, unsurprisingly, I'm usually in combat when I get kills. So how much gold does a kill get you, including when the target has a kill/death streak?

Answer (score 1):

Tl;dr - Gold is distributed diffrent in Proving Grounds than in the Summoners Rift. **Focusing on killing dominating players are more rewarding** than in other League of Legends game types.

I played ARAM moment before and I do some math based on my observations. I can't be sure about gold per kill but I will be sure about killing players and this should show me some rules behind it.

I also make an assumption that Riot based values on V1.0.0.120 Summoners Rift gold per kill values. With this you can see some pattern here.

- 1st kill ? 47% ~ 140 gold - which confirm @Julian G. post.
- 2nd kill ? 52% [*+5% Change*]
- 3rd kill - **Killing killing spree player is 237 G** comparing to **408 (58%)** [*+6% Change*]
- 4th kill - **Killing rampage player is 308 G** comparing to **475 (65%)** [*+7% Change*]
- 5th kill ? (72%) [*+8% Change*]
- 6th kill - **Killing dominating player is 520 G** comparing to **647 (80%)**

Normal reward growth is 20%. In Proving Grounds it growing from 5% to 10% - probably.

Pics with data [image: 1] and [image: 2].

Comment: You may want to use the Print Screen key to take screenshots in the future, rather than your camera.  The quality leaves much to be desired.

Comment: @CurtisTasker - I was playing on iLoL Mac Beta. There aren't such key as a Print Screen on any Mac keybord and doing normal Print Screen key combination don't work with this app. I'm waiting for your better resolution pic and answer in this topic :) !

Comment: On a Mac, press command+shift+3 :)

Comment: @CurtisTasker As I said "doing normal Print Screen key combination don't work with this app". I'm still waiting for your screenshot :>

Comment: Funny, the screenshot key combo works fine for lol on my mac.  Honestly I don't even think a screenshot is necessary to answer this question, it just irked me that you posted a cameraphone picture of a computer screen :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing a custom game of ARAM on Proving Grounds, Champion kills are worth 140g.

Here is a video showing a kill from Nidalee:

[Nidalee ARAM kill](http://youtu.be/BUMRk-5i6tU?t=4s)

I started at right before she gets the kill but you can start it from the beginning.

Answer (score -1):

From the research that I have done I believe that you receive the same amount of gold as if you were playing summoner's rift, but while in the proving grounds you receive a constant stream of gold and experience.

Comment: That's definitely not true. First Blood gives only 200g instead of 400, and for shutting down a legendary streak you get 400 instead of 600. That's pretty much all I can remember for sure though.